# Inscription at Mauerbach Charterhouse (Vienna, Austria)

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I am having a little trouble with a Latin inscription I came across the other day (upper/lower cases as in the original):

> Hanc Rex Cartusiam Fridericus Nomine pulcher Condidit Austriacus
> Religione pius Anno MCCCXIII

Unfortunately, my school Latin has become a bit rusty. Most of the meaning is clear:

> King Frederick [the] Fair founded this Carthusian [monastery] … in the
> year 1313.

But I am unsure about pius, Austriacus and “nomine religione” (which I presume go together). Are *pious* and *Austrian* just further adjectives of Fridericus? And how does the ablative (in the name of religion?) come into play? I thank for and appreciate your comments and insights.

Answer (score 5):

My interpretation would be:

- *Nomine pulcher:* “Called ‘the Fair’” (he was indeed called Frederick the Fair). This usage of the ablative *nomine* with the name in the same case as the named thing or person is quite common, even in classical Latin.
- *Religione pius:* “Pious of faith” or “dutiful in religious matters,” etc. This seems a slightly unusual phrase, although Google finds a few more examples. It bears keeping in mind that *pius* in Latin does not necessarily refer to religion.
- *Austriacus* can only modify *Rex Fridericus* as well.

Thus we get:

> The pious Austrian king Frederick, called the Fair, founded this Charterhouse in the year 1313.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, Frederick the Fair is an historic figure, and indeed the founder auf Mauerbach Charterhouse (even though the inscription was done much later than 1313. The “handsome” byname wasn't even used before 1600 or so.) That said, he's usually (in Latin) referred to as “(Rex) Fridericus Pulcher”, i.e. without the “nomine”, which threw me. But any proximity of words here seems to be coincidental and not give any indication of logical groups anyway.

Comment: @Ingmar My biggest weakness with Latin is scansion, but I have a hunch this is a distich. Others of the good people on this website can maybe tell; but if true, this may account for some of the weirdness, inlcuding the word (dis-)order.